# Loading Google Maps via Ajax call

Tags: javascript, html, google-maps, google-maps-api-3

I saw some questions related to my, but none of them works for me.
I have single page, and on ajax call i'm replacing content of some div to create effect of vieawing page without standard page loading.

in index file i have some div:

```
<div id="dynamic"></div>
```

all other pages html looks like:

```
<div id="dynamic" class="content">
<!-- custom content, will be loaded in index file via ajax, etc -->
</div>
```

And, now piece of JS code:

```
$('.menu a').on('click',function(e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        var url = $(this).attr('href');

        $.ajax({
            url: url,
            dataType: 'html',
            success: function(html) {
                var div = $(html);
                var delay = 100;
                setTimeout(function() {
                    $('#dynamic').html('').append(div.filter('.content').html());
                }, delay);
            }
        });
    })
```

And this is contact page on which google maps works fine on standard page load (when i type contact page url and hit enter), but maps don't work on dynamic ajax call, when i click `.menu a`

```
<div id="dynamic" class="content">
    <div id="map1"></div>
    <script>
        function init_map() {
            var styles = [
            ];

            var myOptions = {
                mapTypeControlOptions: {
                    mapTypeIds: ['Styled']
                },
                center: new google.maps.LatLng(46.4325, 44.5676723),
                mapTypeId: 'Styled',

            };

            var div = document.getElementById('map1');
            var map = new google.maps.Map(div, myOptions);
            var styledMapType = new google.maps.StyledMapType(styles, { name: 'Styled' });
            map.mapTypes.set('Styled', styledMapType);

            marker = new google.maps.Marker({
                map: map,
                position: new google.maps.LatLng(51.4981374, -0.1520723),
                icon: "images/marker.png"
            });
        }

        if (document.getElementById("map1")) {
            google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, 'load', init_map);
        }
    </script>
</div>
```

I've tried to run init_map function inside ajax code, but this does nothing.
Thanks for any advice.

Answer (score 0):

The main idea is that you'd have to take care of google.maps objects (scripts, styles, fonts) to make it work and avoid memory leaks.

You can take a look at my script [here](http://anatolysukhanov.com/load/index.html). When you click "Load Map", the google map defined in [map.html](http://anatolysukhanov.com/load/map.html) shows up.